# How to write this without For loop

Tags: programming, performance-tuning, functional-style

Suppose I have a few lists of numbers and want to exponentiate element-wise, then sum up everything into a polynomial.

For example, if I have

```
a = {1,2,3}
b = {2,4,6}
c = {3,2,1}
```

I would like to get

```
poly = xy^2z^3 + x^2y^4z^6 + x^3y^2z
```

Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with the functional programming style Mathematica is intended to be used for, and I can only write something like

```
For[i = 1, i < Length[a] + 1, i++,
 term = x^Part[a, i]*y^Part[b, i]*z^Part[c, i];
poly = poly + term;]
```

As you may expect, this is taking quite a long time to evaluate. Would anybody have any thoughts as to how I would rewrite this to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can take advantage of [listability](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html?q=Listable&lang=en). As a rule if a function has the `Listable` attribute listable operations will be faster than other alternatives such as mapping.

```
{a, b, c} = Transpose[{a, b, c}];
Apply[Plus, x^a*y^b*z^c]
```

[image]

or

```
{a, b, c} = Transpose[{a, b, c}];
Total[x^a*y^b*z^c]
```

[image]

Comment: This works very well! Thanks to everyone for all the other superb answers in this thread.

Answer (score 5):

Using `MapThread`:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {2, 4, 6};
c = {3, 2, 1};

Apply[Plus, MapThread[x^#1*y^#2*z^#3 &, Transpose[{a, b, c}]]]
```

> x^3 y^2 z + x y^2 z^3 + x^2 y^4 z^6

Answer (score 5):

```
a = {1, 2, 3}; b = {2, 4, 6}; c = {3, 2, 1}; 
Plus @@ Inner[Power, {x, y, z}, Transpose@{a, b, c}, Times]
```

[image]

```
Tr@Inner[Power, {x, y, z}, Transpose@{a, b, c}, Times]
Total@Inner[Power, {x, y, z}, Transpose@{a, b, c}, Times]
Plus @@ Times @@@ Thread@Power[{x, y, z}, Transpose@{a, b, c}]
Tr[Times @@ Power[{x, y, z}, #] & /@ {a, b, c}]
(* etc. *)
```

give the same output.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to write :-)

Comment: @Simon, "de ja vu all over again"? :)

Comment: Obviously a gliche in the matrix =)

Answer (score 4):

Let's do it without having to transpose the input lists.

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}, {3, 2, 1}};
monomialXYZ[{i_, j_, k_}] := x^i y^j z^k
Apply[Plus, Map[monomialXYZ, data]]
```

> x^3 y^2 z + x y^2 z^3 + x^2 y^4 z^6

The last line of the code can be written more succinctly as

```
Plus @@ monomialXYZ /@ data
```